# Create a Google Maps route of a specific distance

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm wondering if there is a method using Google Maps API that will create a route of a specified distance.  An example would be if I wanted to walk 2 miles starting at my house and returning to my house.  The desired result set would would include route options within a certain tolerance (slightly greater than or less than 2 miles).

Answer (score 0):

There are no methods in the Google Maps API for doing what you suggest. The Directions API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) requires that you specify a start and destination address. It's A-to-B rather than A-to-anywhere-within-x-distance.

To do something like what you're suggesting, you would probably need to write your own algorithm to do it, based off of some open mapping data such as Open Street Map (http://www.openstreetmap.org/)